# React Native onChange event doesn't work on mobile

Tags: react-native, mobile, browser, onchange

I have an issue with my React Native. The purpose of my app is to store user input and display the values in an alert. The application works in browser as it should but it doesn't display the values when run on mobile. I looked for a solution online but can't seem to find any answer relevant to my problem.

Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      firstName: "",
      surname: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: ""  
    }
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name] : event.target.value });
  }

  render(){

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
        name="firstName"
        placeholder="Name"
        firstName={this.state.firstName} 
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        style={styles.textBox}
        />
        <TextInput
        name="surname"
        placeholder="Surname"
        surname={this.state.surname} 
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        style={styles.textBox}
        />
        <TextInput
        name="email"
        placeholder="Email"
        email={this.state.email} 
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        style={styles.textBox}
        />
        <TextInput
        name="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        password={this.state.password} 
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        style={styles.textBox}
        secureTextEntry
        />
        <TextInput
        name="confirmPassword"
        placeholder="Confirm password"
        confirmPassword={this.state.confirmPassword} 
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        style={styles.textBox}
        secureTextEntry
        />

        <View >
          <Button 
          onPress={() => {
            alert(
              'Your details are: \n' +
              this.state.firstName + '\n' +  
              this.state.surname + '\n' +
              this.state.email + '\n' 
              );
          }}
          title="Register"
          color='#ff3333'
          width='50'
          borderRadius='6'
          />
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Native events can be bit different than react js events.
For TextInput,
In react native the event name is `onChangeText` and it doesn't return the whole event.
It will return the direct value.

```
 handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({ [value] : value });
  }

 <TextInput
    name="surname"
    placeholder="Surname"
    surname={this.state.surname} 
    onChangeText={this.handleChange}
    style={styles.textBox}
    />
```

Comment: onChangeText fixed my issue, thank you :) but i am now left with event handlers for each attribute becuase I couldn't find a solution where I can have single 'handleChange' for each attribute.